# Discord.js Bots // Say Command

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js, bots

I've coded a "say command" that's supposed to execute a message every time I type in -say.
It's working fine, I just want the prefix to be set to  "?" instead of "-" only for that one command, the other ones are supposed to be set to the main one ("-"). On top of that I want it to *delete the command* after typing it in, so all that remains is the message `[(e.g ?say hello --> (delete "?say hello" --> send message "hello" to text channel)].`  I also want to **specify** the text channel in my command, instead of just setting it to send the messages only to one specific channel `[e.g -say (message) (text channel)]` It would also be pretty cool if it said something like "Done." and deleting that confirmation after ~5 sec.

So here is the code:

```
client.on('message', function(message) {

    if(message.author.bot) return;

    else if(isValidCommand(message, "say")) {

        let sendMessage = message.content.substring(4);

        let sendChannel = client.channels.cache.get('767374258492932106');

        sendChannel.send(sendMessage)
    }
});
```

In the following I will show you my not working code, trying to set the prefix to "?" but it didnt execute, only saying "declaration or statement expecting and missing or wrong punctuation..

```
client.on('message', function(message) {
    if (['?'].every((prefix) => {
    if (!message.content.startsWith(prefix) || message.author.bot) return;

    else if(isValidCommand(message, "say")) {

        let sendMessage = message.content.substring(4);

        let sendChannel = client.channels.cache.get('767374258492932106');

        sendChannel.send(sendMessage)
    }
});
```

It'd be really grateful if someone helped me with this. Thank you!

Comment: You seem to be asking for someone to write some code for you. Stack Overflow is a question and answer site, not a code-writing service. Please [see here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to learn how to write effective questions.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure what you trying to achieve with

```
    if (['?'].every((prefix) => {
```

but this is what I would do

using args, substring and switch to identify the command.

The usage of the

```js
client.on('message', async message =>{
    if (message.author.bot) return;
    if (message.content.startsWith(prefix)) {
        let args = message.content.substring(prefix.length).split(" ");
        switch (args[0].toLowerCase()){
            case 'say': {
        let sendMessage = message.content.substring(prefix.length +args[0].length+ args[1].length + 2); //2 is accounting for the 2 space between prefix and # and prefix and the main content
                setTimeout(()=>{message.delete()},5000)
                let sendChannel = client.channels.cache.get(args[1]); 
                sendChannel.send(sendMessage)
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    if (message.content.startsWith(otherPrefix))    {
        let args = message.content.substring(otherPrefix.length).split(" ");
        switch (args[0].toLowerCase()){
            case 'say': {
        // Do something else
                break;
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Edit: The usage of the commend would be like

```
!say #generalTextChannel abc
```

where #generalTextChannel is tagging the channel

or

```
!say 767374258492932106 abc
```

where 767374258492932106 is the channel Id

Answer (score 0):

I don't quite understand what are you trying to do with the prefixes.
When trying to detect a prefix in front of a command, you can just use the other line you used without `['?'].every`

Use just this: `if (!message.content.startsWith(prefix) || message.author.bot) return;`.
Then check for each command individually under this. `if (command == 'say')`

[A very simple way of getting arguments:](https://anidiots.guide/first-bot/command-with-arguments)

```js
const args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).trim().split(/ +/g);
const command = args.shift().toLowerCase();
```

The say command would look something like this:

```js
if(command == 'say'){
   //then you could find the channel
   //https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/ChannelManager?scrollTo=fetch
   client.channels.fetch('222109930545610754')
       .then(channel => {
         channel.send(args.join(" ")) //sending the arguments joined with a space in the fetched channel
            .then(msg => {setTimeout(function(){msg.delete()},5000)}) //delete after 5 seconds, please check if delete is a function (I didn't)
       })
       .catch(console.error);
}
```

`['?'].every` got me thinking you could use `if(!['?', '-'].some(prefix => content.startsWith(prefix))) return` to use more prefixes instead of the if statement.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what your saying. But here is how I would do it.

```
const Discord = require("discord.js");
const client = new Discord.Client();
const prefix = '!';

client.on('message', message => {

const args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).trim().split(/+ /);
const command = args.shift().toLowerCase();

if (command === 'say') {
if (!message.content.startsWith(prefix) || message.author.bot) return;

const user = message.author;

if (!args[0]) {
user.send("Provide a word to say in the say command\nExample: !say Hello")
}

const say = args.join(" ");
message.channel.send(say)
message.delete()
}

})

client.login("PUT YOUR TOKEN HERE")
```

Answer (score 0):

For the other prefix, you could do this:

```
client.on('message', async message => {

if(message.content === '?say') {
//the code (I don't know what is the code, I'm giving the way for the prefix)
} else {}

if(!message.content.startsWith(prefix) || message.author.bot) return

const args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).trim().split(/+ /);
const command = args.shift().toLowerCase();

//bla bla bla (the rest of the commands, etc.)
}
```